I can't recall the name of a horror movie / TV-show I saw years ago
I'm not sure if this is a nightmare I've had since I was young, because I'm pretty sure I saw this on TV. Anyway, the plot goes something like this:
There's this big mansion, I think it's wine-red, out in the middle of nowhere (in a forest, to be exact). A family, or a group of people in different ages, move in. Weird things start happening. I'm not sure if the kids are possessed, or if they get possessed by the time they've settled in, but there's mostly things going on with them... I think. The adults start going loco, and some of them commit suicide. It's kinda like in the movie Shrooms where you think "the main character" is a victim like everyone else in the group, but in the end you're like 'aha, so she was the murderer', because you assume that there are strange creatures killing them or whatever. Anyway, the monsters in my (hopefully not) nightmare are like... swamp monsters? I don't even know. They look like it. One is red and the other one is green. I think the red one is in the house, while the green one is outside. They seem friendly towards the kids, as far as I know... I didn't watch much of it since I got scared.
It's the one thing I keep dreaming about, which is weird, because I can't find any information about it. No one else I know has seen it either. Also, I saw the movie around 2005 and the only fitting genre I can think of is psychological horror. It basically screws you over.

+1 in hopes you didn't just give a great movie plot away which came from your dreams :D

When you watched it on TV in 2005, was it old or new? Was it in English?

I don't know which movie this could be, but it sounds like Scary Movie 2 is a parody on this movie (amongst a bunch of others). Maybe you can find the movie by checking the 'parodies' section of the Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scary_Movie_2

@poepje I think Scary Movie 2 is mostly a parody of House on Haunted Hill

Could it be Rose Red?

Dr. Joyce Reardon, a psychology professor, leads a team of psychics into the decrepit mansion known as Rose Red. Her efforts unleash the spirit of former owner Ellen Rimbauer and uncover the horrifying secrets of those who lived and died there.

Here is the trailer, maybe parts will look familiar:



